# What is the best way to host asp web application under Default Web Site (port 80) AND as new website (port xxxx) at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've developed regular asp web application to deploy under IIS server as new website binding with port xxxx, then the customer need to publish this site on web server under the  Default Web Site (port 80)

and the problem is all links and redirect urls are hard coded in master pages and sometimes in code behind

my question is what is the best way to modify the code to work on two ways under IIS server
(under  Default Web Site (port 80) and as new website with prot xxxx) ?

like:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainMaster.Master.cs"     Inherits="xxxx.MainMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="/App_Themes/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/App_Themes/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.textarea.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="/App_Themes/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and like in code behind

```
try
{
   Response.Redirect("/Applications/Default.aspx");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Helper.LogException(ex);
}
```

and in some asp pages the jquery:
    function ShowColorBox(id) {

```
    //var reqId = name.reqid;
    // get Request ID from hidden field
    var imageBtn = $("#" + id);
    var requestId = imageBtn.attr('reqid');

    // attach color box to Request Details
    imageBtn.colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "680px", height: "95%", href: "/Applications/Requests/RequestDetails.aspx?ItemID=" + requestId });


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to work around this problem is as following:
1- in Master page I write links like this 
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainMaster.Master.cs" Inherits="xxxx.MainMaster" %>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/App_Themes/styles.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/App_Themes/colorbox.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js") %>'></script>
<script src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.textarea.js") %>'></script>
<script src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js") %>'></script>
<script src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.colorbox.js") %>'></script>
<script src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js") %>'>    </script>
<link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/App_Themes/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" />
```

2- in code behind

```
 Response.Redirect("~/Applications/Default.aspx");
```

3- in asp pages: 
    function ShowColorBox(id) {

```
    //var reqId = name.reqid;
    // get Request ID from hidden field
    var imageBtn = $("#" + id);
    var requestId = imageBtn.attr('reqid');

    // attach color box to Request Details
    imageBtn.colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "680px", height: "95%", href: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Applications/Requests/RequestDetails.aspx?ItemID=") %>' + requestId });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to add an binding of the default web site to the port needed.
This can be done with two or three clicks in the IIS-Manager.

The clean way is to use ~/ and runat="server" wherever you need a link.

Comment: I can't change the port of default website because is used as internet web server (port 80), and I must publish my site under default website as new web application (the ~/ is not enough because you need to write the links like: ~/WebAppName/....) and at the same time I can't do this because the other web application with port xxxx is running

Comment: Well ~/ means "current application" which includes the port and applicationName so that is no problem at all. And you dont have to change the binding of the default web site, but you can just add one binding. So the application running on default web site will listen to port 80 AND XX